# showing contents of textarea as I type

Tags: html, text, textarea, content-type

I am going to make a textarea box for input a text and save it and show it in another part... like comment, ...
but when i put the text in another area it is plain text....no paragraph no space ... nothing... as it shows here in below as a preview ,.....what i should do?

Comment: I suggest you add your code to your question, it'll help people refine it for you =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need an HTML Input Box (something that allows you to format paragraphs, fonts, etc.)

There are a lot of free ones you can find online, and also several you can pay for.  Check out CuteEditor, or Telerik, etc.

Comment: I dont understand your answer.

Comment: paragraphs and spacing is easiest with HTML.  You can input the HTML directly in your first textarea box (e.g.: "<p>Some Text</p>"), but your user would need to 1) know HTML, and 2) not have much to enter or it would become cumbersome/difficult.  To make the HTML input easier, you can use a special control called an "HTML Input box", or something to that effect.  You can get this for free from CuteEditor, FreeTextBox, etc. (please google these to learn more about them), or you can pay for a really nice one from Telerik, etc. (again, please google this one to learn more).

Answer (score 0):

i didn't code it yet... I just want to save the visitors comments (with font styles and paragraphs, url,...) and show it in another page as they write...

i think i have to use a text editor applet (something like this we are using here for writing the comments) ... but maybe there is something more simple ..